# Solving of explicit equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to solve the following equation for the Mach number `M` over an entire flow field:

[image]

Where q_c is defined as

[image]

`γ` is a constant and is the ratio of specific heats (1.4 for air) and `p` is the pressure and is a matrix of the the dimension of the mesh. It is thus an equation with `M` on both sides and needs to be solved explicitly.

Is there a built in MATLAB function or any other way to solve this equation for `M` over the entire flow field?

Comment: So, all you want to do is to solve this equation for every value of *p_ij* from the matrix **p**? Your first step is to solve it for a scalar-valued `p`. Then you'll be able to show us some code and attack the second part of the question: how to vectorize that code. Tell us exactly which part do you have problems with, and if it is with vectorization, we absolutely must see the code first.

Comment: Thank you Kuba. I want to solve for M, I already have p.

Comment: γ=1.4, usually; see [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio). You probably confused it with standard density (≈ 1.225 kg/m³)

Comment: Wait: you say the only matrix/vector in this equation is the pressure `p`, right? You seem to divide that one away, so teh equation is independent of the pressure; the value would be the same everywhere...This is probably not correct, could you correct the equation?

Comment: I see what you are saying @RodyOldenhuis, but am unsure on how to proceed as the equations seem to be right. I would appreciate it if you can take a look at the equations, I found them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_number), note that I am dealing with free stream Mach number in the region of 2.5.

Comment: @Michael_K: Well, it seems there is a problem with the equations on wikipedia. I found [there lecture notes](http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/SPRING/fluids/Spring2008/LectureNotes/f16.pdf), which show a different formula at the end, but I've run out of time here :) So, if I were you, I'd first find out what the *correct* formula is, and then use my answer to solve for `M`.

Comment: Yes thats a good idea. Wikipedia is great but not always that reliable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is a polynomial with non-integer powers:

```
a := 0.88...
N := M²

⇒ N - a²·(½γN + 1)·(1 - 1/7N)²⁵ = 0
```

for which there is no analytic solution. So, you'll have to go numerical. The easiest (but not the fastest) way:

```
gamma = 1.4;
a = 0.88128485;
M = zeros(size(p));

for ii = 1:numel(M)
    M(ii) = fzero(@(M)...
        M - a*sqrt( (gamma/2*p(ii)*M.^2 + 1).*(1-1./7./M.^2).^(2.5) ), ...
        2.5); %# initial value; insert your roughly expected value here
end
```

Comment: Than you very much for the quick help @RodyOldenhuis. I basically just need to calculate it for post processing so speed isn't that important.